# overlay two densities in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the below function which plots density for a_positions. Now, I would like add b_positions which overlay with a_positions with a trasparent colours. How is possible to overlay a_positions and b_positions in one plot with the below function?

```
def plot_density(a_positions, b_positions, chr_name, chr_len, out_fname):
    d = pd.DataFrame(a_positions)
    d.hist(bins=100)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_xlabel(chr_name + " positions")
    ax.set_ylabel("Density")

    ax.set_title('', color='black')
    #plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.25, left=.25)
    plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')

    ax.set_xlim(xmin=1, xmax=chr_len)
    ax.set_xticks(pd.np.linspace(1, chr_len, 5))
    plt.savefig(out_fname)
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame.hist` accepts the `alpha` keyword, which controls the transparency. So, if you set the `alpha` of `b_positions` to something `<1`, then you should be able to see `a_positions` below it.

Here's a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100))

df1.hist(bins=10,color='b')
df2.hist(bins=10,ax=plt.gca(),alpha=0.5,color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why are there 3 colors and not 2?